# Clear localStorage on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, safari, local-storage

How can you clear all localStorage on iOS Safari? Selecting 'Clear history and website data' does not remove localStorage (which seems odd, possibly a bug?).

A similar question was asked on [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112717/clearing-localstorage-on-ipad-or-from-safari-browser-item-seems-to-be-persi) but was closed.

I have recorded [a video showing the issue](https://youtu.be/3STa3uVjbdk) in the iOS9.1 simulator.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be a programming question, so as currently written it doesn’t seem in scope for stack overflow. In contrast, the question you asked at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112717/clearing-localstorage-on-ipad-or-from-safari-browser-item-seems-to-be-persi is about programmatically clearing storage for a single site/origin, and so would actually in scope for stack overflow—if you’d written the same question here. But you’re actually asking a different non-programming question here. (And to be clear, there’s no way from a Web app to clear all local storage on a device.)

Comment: The post on apple.stackexchange.com was not written by me and has now been deleted. It mentioned both programming and manual deletion:

> "I've tried refreshing the browser, I've tried rebooting the ipad (short of a reset of the device), I've tried "Clear History" and "Clear Cookies and DatsStorage" <

...but was closed by moderators because of partial programming content. For future reference the question can be found here https://web.archive.org/web/20150426021822/http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112717/clearing-localstorage-on-ipad-or-from-safari-browser-item-seems-to-be-persi

Answer (score 12):

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-za/HT201265):

> To clear other stored information from Safari, tap Settings > Safari > Advanced > Website Data > Remove All Website Data."

Or, if you want to delete it for a specific site, you can either slide the entry to left and delete it, or you can press edit in the top left and delete what you have to.

Comment: This method does work so I'm not sure why the previous comment says it doesn't.

I'm specifically working on saving messages to localstorage once marked as read, and wiping data using this method does indeed clear the localstorage values.

Answer (score 10):

So as you're seeing some browsers are more stubborn about keeping the local storage than others. One thing you can do is clear the storage using the localStorage API.

```
localStorage.clear() //clears everything in localStorage
localStorage.removeItem("test123") //removes only the specific property "test123"
```

I wrote [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028075320/http://www.richfinelli.com/local-storage-101/) about localStorage, that explains some of the nuances.

I'm not sure how to clear it manually in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

You need to clear the respective db files at **/Library/Safari/Databases** and  **/Library/Safari/LocalStorage**

Open the Finder in your Mac and click on **GO** and **Go to Folder** and paste the above two locations.

Delete the files which have the names of the applications whose data you want to clear.

Comment: this question was for iOS not MacOS

Comment: Oops! My bad :)